# Microsoft Graph API help(graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

This is regarding the Microsoft Graph API explorer related to Teams. I am using the endpoint ('graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages') to fetch all the messages. It is providing list of messages with a 'Conversation Id' field, whose value(Base64 format) changing at times even if it belongs to the same conversation. What is the exact behavior related to this 'Conversation Id' field when will it change and when it will be same ?

Or if there is any other field which will remain constant for a particular conversation.

Answer (score 1):

The API which you are using [/me/messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) is used to get mail messages in the signed-in user's mailbox. You can use [/me/chats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) to retrieve the list of chats that the user is part of.

Microsoft Teams conversations are persistent and retained forever by default. So, these chat Ids are fixed. 
For each of the following chats you will get a fixed id which does not change.

[image]